# WebView not visible when added to content from code behind

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have the following code,  what i`m trying to do is to replace a user control's content with a new Grid, that grid then will host a webviewer. If i test the following code the webviewer is not visible.

```
        Content = ContentGrid;
        ContentGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        ContentGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        var rectangle = new Rectangle();
        rectangle.Height = 300;
        rectangle.Width = 300;
        rectangle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        WebView.Name = "CevaSmecher";
        WebView.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        WebView.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        WebView.Height = 300;
        WebView.Height = 300;
        WebView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        WebView.DefaultBackgroundColor = Colors.Red;

        ContentGrid.Name = "SmecherieRoute";
        ContentGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BlueViolet);
        ContentGrid.Children.Insert(0, WebView);
```

Then i replace the last line with this one and rectangle is visible.

```
ContentGrid.Children.Insert(0, rectangle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. My problem was that, in the UserControl the CacheMode was set to BitmapCache.

```
CacheMode = new BitmapCache();
```

After I removed this line, the WebView appeared.